# How to send find() object from Node.js/Socket.io backend to Angular2?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, angular, socket.io

Ok then, I want to render data from my mongodb using find() method.

```
socket.on('findUserMessages', (userName) => {
userName = userName
io.sockets.connected[socket.id].emit('private message', 
{ type: 'ss', text:userName, user: 'bot' });

db.chat.find({ user: userName }, function (err, docs) {
userName = userName
if (err) throw err;
console.log('load old messages', docs)
})})
```

In node console i recive

```
load old messages
[ { _id: 5888bdd6cef7952e38821f35,
text: 'O rajciu rajciu',
user: 'Adam',
time: 2017-01-25T15:01:42.733Z },
{ _id: 588909469afffb195c0d7a92,
text: 'dasdf',
user: 'Adam',
time: 2017-01-25T20:23:33.069Z } ]
```

My Angular2 service looks like this

```
userLoad(userName:string){
    this.socket.emit('findUserMessages', userName)
}
```

And function from component

```
UserLogin() {
    console.log("ASD");
    this._chatIOService.userLoad(this.user)
}
```

On browser I get

```
ASD
chatIO.component.ts:49 Object {type: "ss", text: "Adam", user: "bot"}
```

I was trying to input 'docs' in

```
io.sockets.connected[socket.id].emit
```

but without any succes.

I will be pleased with any fedback.